# Swift span zoom

Tags: ios, swift

Need simple coding for the span to zoom on the users location when the button is pressed. It follows the user but need span coding help.

i use this atm

```
@IBAction func Refreshbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
//Navigationsknappen

    Mapview.userTrackingMode = .Follow
    self.Locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you.

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.075, 0.075)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:lat, longitude: long), span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: Get fault on "lat and long". How do set them to user location?

Comment: you can hard code current latitude and longitude , if you testing on simulator, you need to set by yourself.

Comment: @Adam CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:12.333, longitude: 12.344)

Comment: yeah it worked. but now need to find users location with long and lat..

Comment: @Adam you wont get current location on simulator, But in iOS Simulator menu, go to Debug -> Location -> Custom Location. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is, Its not that simple -

You need to create a region - MKCoordinateRegion

Get long and lat using MKCoordinateSpan

example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {


    //Get the location you need the span zoom 

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(

        //getPropertyLocation.latitude/longitude already set to CLLocationDegrees in a prior process.
        latitude: self.getPropertyLocation.latitude ,
        longitude: self.getPropertyLocation.longitude
    )

    // Get the span that the mapView is set to by the user. "propertyMapView" is the MKMapView in this example.
    let span = self.propertyMapView.region.span


    // Setup the region based on the lat/lon of the property and retain the span that already exists.
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    //Center the view with some animation.
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

}